# Interacting with CLI app from Mono application

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, mono, command-line-interface

I am developing a Windows Forms application for Mono platform. I need to use a third-party software  which has a command-line interface accessible through terminal. How can I interact with that app from my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class will allow you to start and interact with a command line application.

Use [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfbyhds5.aspx) to setup the process and how you would interact with it (`UseShellExecute = false;` then ensure redirection of standard input/output/error).

See [this simple example](http://www.mono-project.com/Howto_PipeOutput) on the mono site.

Comment: @chrfin - Yes, just took the time to look it up before writing something potentially wrong.